# asp.net Grid - how to wrap text in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit

I am displaying data(wrapped) in grid but when i am clicking on edit button is is not showing complete data because textbox is very small(data not wrapped). any help please...

[image: image is showing the two states(edit and normal)]

Sample Code Line:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason(NotDone)" SortExpression="tReason">
      <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tReason") %>'>
         </asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tReason") %>' ></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="SeaGreen" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

........
On page load i am using the following code:

`GridView1.Attributes.Add("style", "word-break:break-all; word-wrap:break-word");`

Comment: I am using Template field<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason(NotDone)" SortExpression="tReason">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tReason") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tReason") %>' ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="SeaGreen" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Set `TextMode="Multiline"` and `Rows="4"` put row number as desired. Maybe to the greatest value possible to wrap your data.

Comment: What will be minimum reason length ??

Comment: Thanks a Lot Akash Multiline is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the textbox a multiline.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tReason") %>' 
TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael. But i am using Grid and when i click on edit button in grid it is showing default size(as in <tr><td>)...........

Comment: Sample ....<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="vOrgName" SortExpression="vOrgName" Visible="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vOrgName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vOrgName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Michael......You are right it is working in grid ...My mistake sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Akash & Michael for the quick response......i have done like this and it is working in grid .....please suggest if it is correct way ........asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason (If not Done)" SortExpression="tReason">
                        
                            ' TextMode="Multiline" Rows="10">
                        
                        
                            ' >